# Why does URL shortening service send response with HTTP status codes 301 and caching headers that does not allow browser to cache?

Tags: http, url-shortener

Why does URL shortening services like goo.gl and bit.ly send url resolution responses with HTTP status codes 301 and caching headers that does not allow browser to actually cache? As a consequence, it always has to go to the shortening service even if the url is same which was previously resolved? In my opinion, 301 responses (permanent redirects) are meant to be cached. If not forever, than at the least for few minutes.

**Relevant HTTP headers in a response from bit.ly**

```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=90
```

**Relevant HTTP headders in a response from goo.gl**

```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: One word: *click tracking.*

Comment: @deceze, why not use 302 when tracking, and 301 when not tracking?

Comment: @deceze That's _two_ words :P

Answer (score 3):

As @deceze has pointed out the reason for disabling/limiting caching is for tracking/analytics, but the reason for using permanent redirects (301) vs temporary redirect (302/307) is to ensure "link juice" or SEO value of the link goes unharmed. This way you can use the shortened links freely in everywhere without worrying about the devaluation of link quality and retain your site's search engine ranking for that page.